# Cut off last half of String

Tags: java, string

I need to cut off half of a user-entered string. I've tried this and it didn't work:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nameOne = sc.nextLine();
    chars[] oneChars = new char[nameOne.length];
    double oneLength = oneChars.length / 2;
    Math.round(oneLength);
    int oneLen = (int)oneLength;
    String nameOneFinal = "";
    for(int i = 0; i == oneLen--; i++) {
        oneChars[i] = oneChars[oneLen];
        nameOneFinal = nameOneFinal + oneChars[i];
    }
```

Comment: How about using String#substring()?

Comment: Why not use Substring method?

Comment: Show a input output example. I don't understand your requirement and your code is complicated to interpret due to some logical errors...

Answer (score 3):

```
final int mid = nameOne.length() / 2;
String[] parts = {
    nameOne.substring(0, mid), // 1st part
    nameOne.substring(mid), // 2nd part
};
```

Answer (score 2):

using `substring` method ... you can do it
Ex:

```
public String extraEnd(String str) {

 String s = str.substring(str.length()/2);//it will have the last half of string 

 return s ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SubString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method to get this

```
String str = "CutThisBytwo";
int len = str.length();
String firstHalfStr = str.substring(0, len/2);
String secondHalfStr = str.substring(len/2,len );
System.out.println(firstHalfStr);
System.out.println(secondHalfStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

The easy way: using `String.substring(int index1, int index2)`

The hard way:

```
String new = "";

for(int i = 0; (i < old.length() - 1) / 2; i++){

    new += old.charAt(i);

}
```

If it's for a homework, the hard way might get you brownie points, but if not just stick to the easy way.

Comment: You use **new** as variable name. new is reserved word for Java. This example will result in an error;